# Youtube API wont work after changing display-setting on mobile

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api, video-player

My youtube player (embedded from js-api) just works like it should be.

However, I do not want to show the player by default. So I placed the player in a div, which i set to 'display:none;'. After I change  this setting by pressing the 'play-button' div, the video appears and starts to play. At least on my desktop. On my Android phone this does not work.

Any thoughts what the problem could be? See an example at:
http://www.peterbastiaan.nl/upload/test.php

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe player.playVideo(); only works on desktop.
It will work on mobile but only after the user clicks the actual video first. 
If you simply display the video without automatically playing it, it should work. Probably

Comment: Looks like it won't work on mobile apparently.. Thanks for your response!